# Different behaviour of filesystem redirector on Win2003R2 x64 and Win7 x64

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, 64-bit, wow64

I have the following minimal application compiled with x86 configuration that illustrate my question:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPVOID oldValue = NULL;
    BOOL result = ::Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&oldValue);
    _ASSERTE(result);

    HMODULE moduleHandle = ::LoadLibrary(L".\\mymodule.dll");
    if (moduleHandle != NULL)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Succeeded";
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD errorCode = ::GetLastError();
        std::wcout << L"Failed with error code = " << errorCode;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

mymodule.dll is x86 dynamic library image that depends on iphlpapi.dll.

When I run this program under Windows 2003 R2 x64 SP2 I get the output "Failed with error code = 193" (193 is ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT) and system message box with message that iphlpapi.dll not found.
Process Monitor shows that the iphlpapi.dll was searched under System32 folder.

When I run the same executable (and mymodule.dll also the same) under Windows 7 x64 SP1 I get the output "Succeeded" and Process Monitor shows that iphlpapi.dll was searched under SysWOW64 and successfully found.

Why the behaviour is different on those two x64 OSes?

Comment: My guess would be that on Win7, iphlpapi.dll had already been loaded in the app's memory before you called `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`. You can call `GetModuleHandle()` before calling `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` to check that.

Comment: Remy's comment sounds very plausible. This is a fine example of why you should not call `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`. The documentation for `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` tell you that DLL load failures are a consequence of calling the function.

Comment: Please note the code above is a complete program. It would be strange if this program would have a dependency on such a specific module as iphlpapi.dll by default, wouldn't it? I called GetModuleHandle and it returned NULL, and GetLastError = ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND. Besides this question arose from debugging existing software and curiosity, so I cannot just "do not call Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection".

Comment: Did you verify (not with `_ASSERTE()` but by looking at the actual return value) that `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` is actually succeeding under Win7?  Output the actual result to `std::wcout`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind [this note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743.aspx): "Disabling file system redirection affects only operations made by the current thread. Some functions, such as `CreateProcessAsUser()`, do their work on another thread, which is not affected by the state of file system redirection in the calling thread." So maybe `LoadLibrary()` uses an internal worker thread under Win7 but not under Win2K3?

Comment: Or maybe Win7 is just smarter than Win2K3 and knows to ignore the System32 folder when loading DLLs from a system folder into a 32-bit process so it can avoid trying to load 64-bit DLLs, which is a guaranteed failure.  Who knows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for your guesses. I checked those related to the assert and worker thread and they wasn't confirmed. May be the issue in mymodule.dll. I will try to build a minimal one and see if it matters.